# Not able to run python file

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am a beginner in python and I experienced a problem while executing some code I wrote in VS. I clicked on run python file option but it didnt do anything.

```
import string
from words import words
import random
import string
def valid_word(words):
    word= random.choice(words)
    while "-" in word or " ":
        word= random.choice(words)
    return word.upper()
def hangman():
    word= valid_word(words)
    word_letters= set(word) #letters in  the word
    alphabets= set(string.ascii_uppercase)
    used_letter= set() #what the user has guessed
    while ():
        user_letter= input("Guess a letter:").upper() # user input
        if  user_letter in alphabets - used_letter:
            used_letter.add(user_letter)
            if user_letter in word_letters:
                word_letters.remove(user_letter)
        elif user_letter in used_letter:
            print("You have already used that character. Please try again")
        else:
            print("Invalid Input. Kindly Try Again")
hangman()
```

-code I wrote
Keep in mind the terminal didnt show any error and there were no bugs it only showed this- (Aditya Rai) PS C:\Users\Aditya Rai\Code> & "c:/Users/Aditya Rai/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/Users/Aditya Rai/Code/Python/Hangman/main.py" and showed Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases. in output Please help

Comment: Did you try running "python your_file_name"?

Comment: is python installed ? if yes then is it's path present in environment variables ? 
you can refer to this tutorial for installing python: [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-windows)
It looks like 'python' command is not found in windows CMD so either it is not installed or it's path is not present in environment variables.